# Using google analytics API - The 'Getting Started' tutorial

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

So I'm all new to using Google API's, so bear with me :)

I've started with the tutorial for getting started with google embed analytics API, at this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started

Just for notice, I'm working in PHP.

By following the tutorial, I've made it possible to sign in to the google account, and my page displays the logged in google account, and displays 3 dropdown menus, 1 for 'account', 1 for 'property' and 1 for 'view'.

Now when I look at the tutorial site, you have the option to select entities from these drop downs, and furthermore theres a graph displayed below.

Image from tutorial site: https://developers.google.com/analytics/images/embed-api-screenshot.png

However, In my case, I have my logged in account displayed, but my 3 drop down menus are empty, meaning I cant select anything(In the tutorial a 'store' is selected), and furthermore, I have no graph/chart displayed below.

My app looks like this:

[image]

I'm guessing that I need to set these things up in my google dashboard somehow, but I'm not sure as to how I should go about this? If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: "Baring" with you would get me arrested for public indecency (it is "bear with me"), if you use the embed API you do not work with PHP (Embed API is a JavaScript API client) and if you do not see  accounts then you probably do not have access to any GA accounts (the embed API uses the account your are currently logged in  with to Google, and it might be that this email address has not been added to any GA accounts).

Comment: Ahh, I'll correct the bear problem immediately :) When you say GA accounts, what exactly do you mean? I enabled the google analytics api in my dashboard, as the tutorial described, and it is that exact google account im signing in as. Thanks for your answer btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eike was completely correct - I needed to setup a GA account, and register a website. GA had some info that I followed, which included putting a certain script on my website, to allow tracking of my site.

I Now have a working implementation, so thanks to Eike! :)